# My jQuery mobile ajax links don't load my styles

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

When I use the ajax feature to link pages within my app, my pesonnal stylesheet I linked in the `<head>` doesn't apply to the linked page. It's allright when I add the `data-ajax="false"` to my anchors...

What I tried and didn't work :

- Import my personal stylesheet from jquerymobile stylesheet
- Import jquerymobile stylesheet from my personal stylesheet
- Adding my personal stylesheet in the jquerymobile stylesheet

Any idea ?

Comment: Is the stylesheet you try to apply linked to in the header of the initial jquery mobile page, or are you only linking to it in the subsequent page ?

Comment: interesting... the headrr of subsequent pages is ignored by jqm (except with data-ajax=false), but if you linked in the header of the 1st page it is surprising it does not work. Is style correctly applied on the 1st page ?

Comment: Yes ! I modified the listitem styles successfully.

Comment: I really need help on this guys ! Didn't anybody had this problem ?

Comment: Can you set up a demonstration of your issue ? Post the code to your two pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again this morning and I realized I had something wrong : I forgot to give a unique id to my different pages in the following div, it seems to work now.

Home page

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">content...<div>
```

Linked page :

```
<div data-role="page" id="resource">content...<div>
```